# Ora-00905 missing keyword error

Tags: oracle

Im getting below error while executing below line,

```
SELECT  * INTO employee_Backup  FROM employee
```

Error:

**Ora-00905 missing keyword error**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be

```
INSERT INTO employee_backup 
  SELECT * 
  FROM employee
```

Discussed [here](https://forums.oracle.com/message/2308626)

And the syntax is

```
INSERT INTO table_name
  SELECT * 
  FROM table_name
```

Comment: If I execute "INSERT INTO employee_backup 
  SELECT * 
  FROM employee", I am getting ORA-00942 table or view does not exist.

Comment: @Srinivasan try CREATE TABLE employee_backup AS (SELECT * FROM employee);

Answer (score 1):

This is sql-server syntax you're trying to use.
The Oracle equivalent would be:

```
INSERT INTO employee_backup
(SELECT * FROM employee)
```